# React-Native: Get current page in FlatList when using pagingEnabled

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlastList that looks like this:

```
<FlatList
     pagingEnabled={true}
     horizontal={true}
     showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
     data={[ {key:"A"}, {key:"B"} ]}
     renderItem={ ({item, index}) => <MyComponent /> }
 />
```

I have the width of the component set so that only one page shows up on screen at a time. How do I determine what the current page is (or alternatively, the current component being shown)?

Comment: I have a question. Where is `pagingEnabled` coming from? I don't see it as part of the API.

Comment: @NaderDabit That is a great question. It's not in the documentation, but it just works (at least for now). I originally had a ScrollView, which has ```pagingEnabled```, and when I transitioned to the FlatList, it just kept working. Even looking at the React Native code, I can't quite understand why it works. I assume the props are being passed to the underlying ScrollView, but I can't determine where that is happening.

Comment: Ah, I see it is passed down to the underlying scrollView as a prop. Very cool, learn something new everyday!
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js

Comment: Yup, you can see the line here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L283

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I built a component with a `VirtualizedList` like yours, with paging enabled. I used the ScrollView's `onMomentumScrollEnd` handler to determine the current page based on the contentOffset. The `onMomentumScrollEnd` handler is called when the scroll animation stops after the user swipes between pages. It has an event object like the standard `onScroll` event. You can use the `nativeEvent.contentOffset.x` to determine which page you are on like this:

```
class Example extends React.Component {

  onScrollEnd(e) {
    let contentOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
    let viewSize = e.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement;

    // Divide the horizontal offset by the width of the view to see which page is visible
    let pageNum = Math.floor(contentOffset.x / viewSize.width);
    console.log('scrolled to page ', pageNum);
  }

  render() {
    return 
      <VirtualizedList 
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        onMomentumScrollEnd={this.onScrollEnd} />
  }
}
```

I left other `VirtualizedList` props to save space. The `FlatList` component is built on `VirtualizedList`, so the example should work for you.

Comment: Where is ```onMomentumScrollEnd``` in the documentation? I can't seem to find it in ```VirtualizedList```. Is it part of a third-party library?

Comment: Never mind, I found it in the code. It's really frustrating how incomplete the documentation is. Your solution worked great! I was able to keep using the FlatList as well.

Comment: Yes, the ScrollView event handlers aren't documented as well as they could be.

Comment: You are awesome. I could not find any docs related to this. You saved my day. Thank you so much.

Comment: It will be better if you use Math.round instead of Math.floor

Comment: When I try to call any method in onScrollEnd the error "this.methodName is not a function", How to solve it?

Comment: @Vivek if you need to reference "this" in the callback, make sure `onScrollEnd` has been bound to it. Either do `this.onScrollEnd = this.onScrollEnd.bind(this)` in the constructor, or do `onMomentumScrollEnd={this.onScrollEnd.bind(this)}`.

Comment: I have Tabs and activated 'bg' based on Page visible, it's work well, but i got little dealy after get the page and setState based on the page number, is that's because `onMomentumScrollEnd` take time to end?

Comment: If you use this in conjunction with `RefreshControl` then you might want to do this instead: `pageNum = Math.max(0, pageNum);` because otherwise you'll get `pageNum == -1` when you pull to refresh.

Comment: What do I do with the `pageNum` once I found it? How do I use it with the `FlatList`'s `pagingEnabled` field?

Answer (score 7):

You can use onMomentumScrollEnd of Flatlist to detect page change event.

And based on the mobile dimensions_width and listItem size, calculate the pageNumber using below formula.

```
let onScrollEnd = (e) => {
    let pageNumber = Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / dimensions_width + 0.5) + 1, 0), listItems.length);
    console.log(pageNumber); 
}

<FlatList
 pagingEnabled
 horizontal
 onMomentumScrollEnd={onScrollEnd}
 data={listItems}
 renderItem={ ({item, index}) => <MyComponent /> }
/>
```

Comment: What do I do with the `pageNumber` once I found it? How do I use it with the `FlatList`'s `pagingEnabled` field?